# How to align text that is next to a photo?

Tags: html, css, alignment

The heading is not perfectly aligned to the top of photo

**HTML code :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="basic.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="main">
         <div class="content">
            <section>
               <article>
                  <img class="img" src="http://gallery.photo.net/photo/7501614-md.jpg">
                  <div class="p">
                     <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                     dfdsf dasf ad sfdf ddas dfdf adsds fdffda
                     dfdsf dasf ad sfdf ddas dfdf adsds fdffda
                     dfdsf dasf ad sfdf ddas dfdf adsds fdffda
                     dfdsf dasf ad sfdf ddas dfdf adsds fdffda
                     dfdsf dasf ad sfdf ddas dfdf adsds fdffda
                     dfdsf dasf ad sfdf ddas dfdf adsds fdffda
                     dfdsf dasf ad sfdf ddas dfdf adsds fdffda
                     dfdsf dasf ad sfdf ddas dfdf adsds fdffda
                     dfdsf dasf ad sfdf ddas dfdf adsds fdffda
                     dfdsf dasf ad sfdf ddas dfdf adsds fdffda
                     dfdsf dasf ad sfdf ddas dfdf adsds fdffda
                     dfdsf dasf ad sfdf ddas dfdf adsds fdf
                  </div>
               </article>
            </section>
            2
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**CSS code :**

```
.main{
      width: 960px;
      margin: 0px auto;
}

.content{
         float: left;
}


.img{
     float: left;
}
```

[**Demo code**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/focAz)

Answer (score 1):

Just add margin-top:2px to .img or add `h1 {line-height: 1;vertical-align:baseline;}` to your css. It's a common problem with line-height to align text next to images. For illustration have a look e.g. here: [Line-height alignment problems](http://www.brunildo.org/test/va_lineheight.html)

Comment: @MaryMelody Dont' mind :) We're just here to help, this is no competition.

Answer (score 0):

**Set** `h1 {line-height: 1;}` - **[TRY DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rkdgup09/9/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="content">
        <section>
            <article>
                <img class="img" src="http://gallery.photo.net/photo/7501614-md.jpg">
                <div class="p"><h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
                    dfdsf dasf ad sfdf ddas dfdf adsds fdffda
                    dfdsf dasf ad sfdf ddas dfdf adsds fdffda
                    .........................................
                </div>
            </article>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
h1 {line-height: 1;} /* or 0.9 */

.main {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.content {
    float: left;
}
.img {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: If I do that the heading will go to the top of photo, I don't want that, I want to the heading next to the photo but perfectly aligned to the top of the photo

Comment: @apache What do you mean - The heading is not perfectly aligned to "the top of photo"???

Comment: my problem is not the margin right,  I want the heading to align at the top of the photo

Comment: @apache Look at my answer now :)

Comment: @matthias_h Ahh... Sorry, I didn't notice :)

Comment: @MaryMelody Don't mind :) Just happens when one is editing an answer while someone else is doing the same

Comment: @apache it depends on the text-content - e.g. for a capital L change the value to line-height: 0.9; or play around with the value until it's ok for you

Comment: thanks, but look at this website he didn't use the line-height but it is perfectly aligned   http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/demos/web-design-course-demo/

Comment: @apache Try to ZOOM on the page, because it's not perfectly aligned - TRY IT YOURSELF! :)

Comment: @apache he uses line-height, it's inherited from the reset.css - line-height 21px and font-size 24px. Different approach, same result. You'll notice that the headline is moved some pixels up outside of the wrapping div when you highlight / mark it in e.g. Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fig caption Tag

or

You can use Below code for set Heading on Image

```
Tex-align:center;
```